# Crontab not running a python3 script

Tags: python, cron, webhooks

I have the following problem.
I have a script that is in the `/opt/send-message/` directory:

```
from json import dumps
from httplib2 import Http
workdir="/opt/send-message/"
"""Hangouts Chat incoming webhook quickstart."""
url = 'https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/AAAA-JXmA-c/messages?key=' \
      '<key>&token=' \
      '<token>'
txt=open(workdir+"a.txt",'r')
txt=txt.read()
lista_cac=['"','{','}','[',']',',','description']
for c in lista_cac:
    txt=txt.replace(c,"")
txt=txt.split("\\n")
print(txt)
for i in txt:
    troca=i.replace("id:","Ofensa: "+" ")
    if troca.find("P5") != -1:
        bot_message = {'text':"*"+troca+"*"}
        message_headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}
        http_obj = Http()
        print(dumps(bot_message))
        response = http_obj.request(
                uri=url,
                method='POST',
                headers=message_headers,
                body=dumps(bot_message),
        )
        print(response)
# [END hangouts_python_webhook]
```

Running it manually it works perfectly, but using crontab we can't run it. It appears in the CronTab logs that it was successful, but it does not actually execute: `*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /opt/send-message/run.py`
Execution log (cron file):
`Jun  5 18:26:01 machine-linux CROND[7419]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/python3 /opt/send-message/run.py)` 
We still try to:

- Create an executable using nuitka 3
- Create a virtualenv and run inside it
- Migrate to requests
- Run from another linux distro (We are using RHEL and moved to a Debian)
  We performed all these attempts and faced the same scenario, they all work but bash does not execute, any ideas?!

Comment: Does the user this runs under via cron have sufficient privilege for `/opt/send-message`?

Comment: In theory yes, it is the root user of the asset!